# Web Scraping Github for existing projects using a keyword

Tags: python, github, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I've written a code for a Github Web Scraper that scrapes the github search page of a specific keyword and scrapes any existing projects that have appeared after the search is done. The code doesn't work and returns empty data frame. Can anyone please help me rectify what went wrong?

```
rep_link=[]
description=[]
date=[]
url = "https://github.com/search?q=excel+import&type=repositories"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, features="html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())

for a in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'Box-sc-g0xbh4-0 jUbAHB'}):
    rep = a.find('a',href=True, attrs={'class':'Link__StyledLink-sc-14289xe-0 bJBoUI'})
    descp = a.find('span', attrs={'class':'Text-sc-17v1xeu-0 kWPXhV search-match'})
    dt = a.find('span', attrs={'class':'Text-sc-17v1xeu-0 gPDEWA'})
    rep_link.append(rep.text)
    description.append(descp.text)
    date.append(dt.text)

tem = list(zip(rep_link,description,date))
df = pd.DataFrame(data=tem, columns=["Repo","Description","Date"])
```

Im scraping for projects that have the search terms "Excel import", as mentioned in the url. Then in the various results, I wish to scrape the user repo link, the description and the last updated date. I might have gotten the class attributes wrong, please help me out.

Comment: There's a [GitHub Search API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/search?apiVersion=2022-11-28) and that's what you should be using instead of scraping.

Answer (score 0):

[As baduker commented, it's better to use the  [GitHub Search API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/search?apiVersion=2022-11-28) for this; but also,] you should be using different `attrs` for each column -  you need to inspect `soup` more thoroughly to figure out which attributes are common to *all* the sections you want each column value from.

<sup>**(Keep in mind that the `r.text` you request can be different from what you inspected on your browser and attributes that seem to be randomly generated - like *`Box-sc-g0xbh4-0 jUbAHB`*/*`Link__StyledLink-sc-14289xe-0 bJBoUI`*/*`Text-sc-17v1xeu-0 kWPXhV`*/*`Text-sc-17v1xeu-0 gPDEWA`* - are prone to changing and are therefore not reliable for scraping; look for more human-readable attributes which are less likely to change.)**</sup>

---

If you edit your `for` loop to something like

```py
for repo in soup.findAll('li', attrs={'class': 'repo-list-item'}):
    rep = repo.find('a', attrs={'href': True, 'class':'v-align-middle'})
    descp = repo.find('p', attrs={'class': 'mb-1'})
    dt = repo.find('relative-time', attrs={'datetime': True}) 

    date.append(dt['datetime']) 
    rep_link.append(rep['href'])
    description.append(None if descp is None else descp.text.strip()) 
    ## not all repos have description
```

then `df` might look something like

[image: opdf]